# Why is Angularjs code not rendering in rails even though Angularjs is running?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, haml

I'm trying to implement some angularjs into my Rails application.

I've done the following, and Angular is running (I typed `angular` into dev console) but not rendering/executing my angular code in my HAML file.

a. Added angular to my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rails-assets.org'
gem "rails-assets-angular"
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rails-assets-angular-mocks'
end
```

b. Added `//= require angular` and `//= require angular/admin/adminApp` (my Angular App file) to app/assets/javascripts/application.js

c. Enabled Angular by adding `%html{ 'ng-app' => true }` to the  tag in the layout app/views/layouts/application.html.haml

d. Added an adminApp:

```
adminApp = angular.module('adminApp', ['ngResource'])
```

e. Added and adminController:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('adminApp')
  .controller('AdminCtrl', function ($scope, $http) { 
  $scope.test = "This is working!"
  });
```

f. Added the following to one of my app's index.html.haml:

**UPDATE: changed haml so that angular elements are inside the ng-controller div**

```
%div{"ng-controller" => "AdminCtrl"}
   {{test}}
   %p Hello {{"World" + "!"}}
```

**Upon loading that page, I get the non-angularized output:**

{{test}}
Hello {{"World" + "!"}}

From everything I've read, it should be working. Just not sure where I've gone wrong. Have I missed anything?

Comment: Unless you've incorrectly pasted that into SO, your `{{test}}` is not within your `%div{"ng-controller" => "AdminCtrl"}`

Comment: @Jon thanks for catching that. Fixed it and still not rendering angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are injecting [ngResource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/).
It's not included by default in angular so you need add the following if you want to use it:

in the **Gemfile**: `gem "rails-assets-angular-resource"`

**application.js**: `//= require angular-resource`

Also change `%html{ 'ng-app' => true }` to `%html{'ng-app' => "adminApp"}`

Comment: Good call on all of that. I made those changes and still nothing. Anything else we should try? Am I doing this the right way?

Comment: Nothing. Everything is clean as far as javascript errors go. Thanks again for your help, really appreciated!

Comment: Actually, just checked again and there are two:

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function common.js?body=1:3

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function contact_us_home.js?body=1:13

Comment: My guess here is that the error comes from another Javascript file, could you try removing the inclusion of all other JS files in your **application.js**?

Comment: Did that and Angular worked. The issue ended up being `//= require_tree .` in my application.js file. I removed that and everything went smoothly.

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could have been of any help :)